# Is there a way to defer a transition to S3 power state?

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, power-management

I'm wondering if there's a way to defer transition to S3 power state, for instance due to pending results from some external module, e.g. `crypto-engine`?

Picture example scenario: user-space client calls ioctl which is translated by my kernel module into call to external `crypto-engine`. Halfway thru, my module gets `PM_SUSPEND_PREPARE` notification. Can I defer the suspension somehow, not permanently, of course?

Regards,
Marek